# How to make ruby csv table order columns based on headers for each row?

Tags: ruby, csv

Using ruby's CSV::Table class for the first time, I ran across this behavior, which I find odd:

```rb
require 'csv'
r0 = CSV::Row.new(['a','b','c'], [], true)
r1 = CSV::Row.new(['a','b','c'], [10,11,12])
r2 = CSV::Row.new(['c','b','a'], [22,21,20])
t = CSV::Table.new([r0,r1,r2])
t.to_csv

# Expected Output:
# => "a,b,c\n10,11,12\n20,21,22\n"

# Actual Output:
# => "a,b,c\n10,11,12\n22,21,20\n"
```

I assumed that since each row has headers defined that the table would respect those headers, but it seems to ignore them. Looking at the docs, I don't see a way to sort all rows in a consistent way. Is there an option or method that I'm not seeing?

It's easy enough to sort stuff consistently before creating the rows, sure, but it's also easy enough to do without the csv table class altogether--I was kinda hoping for a little more polish from a stdlib class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Table` docs say "All rows are assumed to have the same headers.". We can see that, if the `headers:` keyword is not provided, then the headers are taken *from the first row*.

```
# csv/table.rb
class CSV
  class Table
    # Constructs a new CSV::Table from +array_of_rows+, which are expected
    # to be CSV::Row objects. All rows are assumed to have the same headers.
    def initialize(array_of_rows, headers: nil)
      # ..
      unless @headers
        # ..
          @headers = @table.first.headers
```

Comment: Yeah,  it makes sense why, it's just unexpected imo--I assumed "same headers" referred to values, not necessarily position. When I call `t.values_at('a')` in the example, I'll get the expected 10 and 20 values, so it's a bit inconsistent in that it sometimes considers column headers and other times not... Anyway, thanks for the code snippet

Comment: The behavior surprised me also, but it is documented.